# How to plot data from an xbee in real time with python?

Tags: python, plot, real-time, xbee, pyqtgraph

i need to plot data from an xbee in real time with the pyqtgraph library. Ive tried with the code from some examples but it either graphs the random data from the example or it receives data from the xbee because i cant use a single cycle for both things, and if i try to plot the data from the xbee to the pyqtgraph it gives me an error. Heres the code i have without the pyqtgraph implementation

```
import serial
import time
from xbee import ZigBee

serial_port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

def print_data(data):
    strDatos = data['rf_data']
    tempData = strToList(strDatos)
    phInc = tempData[0].strip()
    tInc = tempData[1].strip()
    print "pH: ", phInc, " Temperatura: ", tInc, " Hora: ", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " Fecha: ", time.strftime("%d/%m")

def strToList(strLista):
    strLista = strLista.split()
    return strLista

zigbee = ZigBee(serial_port, escaped=True, callback = print_data)

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.001)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

zigbee.halt();
serial_port.close()
```

Comment: Why can't you modify `print_data()` to pass the values on to your graphing implementation?  Maybe share the code you're using to graph random data.  Is it possible to add points to your graph over time, or does it expect a complete list of data points in a single call?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chrisRubiano/44e9a4219491c8600595 heres the code with the pyqtgraph implementation, but when i try to replace line 52 with 'data5[i+1,1] = int(phInc)' i get the following error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.00'

Comment: `8.00` is a `float`, not an `int`.  This question has some pointers on converting between the two.  You will probably have to convert the `string` `'8.00'` to a `float` first, and then convert that to an `int`.